# Python, datetime "time gap" percentage

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

Assume I have these datatime variables:

```
start_time, end_time, current_time
```

I would like to know how much time left as percentage by checking `current_time` and the time delta between `start_time` and the `end_time`

IE: Assume the interval is a 24 hours betwen start_time and end_time yet between `current_time` and `end_time`, there are 6 hours left to finish, %25 should be left.

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.7.x, time delta has a method total_seconds to achieve this:

```
import datetime

startTime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
endTime = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=4)

rest = endTime - datetime.datetime.now()
total = endTime - startTime
print "left: {:.2%}".format(rest.total_seconds()/total.total_seconds())
```

In Python 3.2, you can apparently divide the time deltas directly (without going through total_seconds).

(This has also been noted in [Python 2.6.5: Divide timedelta with timedelta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694835/python-2-6-5-divide-timedelta-with-timedelta).)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hackish workaround: compute the total number of microseconds between the two values by using the `days`, `seconds`, and `microseconds` fields. Then divide by the total number of microseconds in the interval.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly simplest:

```
import time

def t(dt):
  return time.mktime(dt.timetuple())

def percent(start_time, end_time, current_time):
  total = t(end_time) - t(start_time)
  current = t(current_time) - t(start_time)
  return (100.0 * current) / total
```