# Python 2.6.5: Divide timedelta with timedelta

Tags: python, division, timedelta

I'm trying to divide one `timedelta` object with another to calculate a server uptime:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> installation_date=datetime.datetime(2010,8,01)
>>> down_time=datetime.timedelta(seconds=1400)
>>> server_life_period=datetime.datetime.now()-installation_date
>>> down_time_percentage=down_time/server_life_period
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.timedelta' 
           and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

I know this [has been solved in Python 3.2](http://bugs.python.org/issue2706), but is there a convenient way to handle it in prior versions of Python, apart from calculating the number of microseconds, seconds and days and dividing?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I perform divison on a datetime.timedelta in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865618/how-can-i-perform-divison-on-a-datetime-timedelta-in-python)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Python ≥2.7, there is [a `.total_seconds()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) to compute the total seconds contained in the timedelta:

```
>>> down_time.total_seconds() / server_life_period.total_seconds()
0.0003779903727652387
```

Otherwise, there is no way but to compute the total microseconds (for versions **< 2.7**)

```
>>> def get_total_seconds(td): return (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 1e6) / 1e6
... 
>>> get_total_seconds(down_time) / get_total_seconds(server_life_period)
0.0003779903727652387
```

Comment: @Adam: The 2nd method works on 2.6. (Of course it is the just that "apart from" solution.)

Comment: @kennytm The second method was great for 2.6. You need to divide td.microseconds by 1000000 though, or the calculation can be off significantly.

Comment: @AndrewRiker There is already a `/ 1e6` at the end of the function?

Comment: @kennytm thanks for the update. Missed the right scroll in my browser.