# Python 2.7 Getting error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to calculate the implied volatility of options pricing. Here i am trying to calculate the Time to Expiry using the below code
But its giving me error

```
import sys
import json

import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

from py_vollib.black_scholes.implied_volatility import *


currentTime = datetime(2020, 11, 15, 15, 30)
expiryTime = datetime(2020, 11, 19, 15, 30)

tl = expiryTime - currentTime
print(tl)
a = tl/timedelta(days = 1)

t = tl/365

iv = implied_volatility(371.85, 28594.30, 28500, t, 0.1, 'P') #ltp, underlaying price, strike, time, risk free rate, type (C,P call or put)
iv = round(iv*100, 2)
print(iv)
quit()
```

```
OutPut
4 days, 0:00:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "option_chain_calculator.py", line 17, in <module>
    a = tl/timedelta(days = 1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you could do it in python3, this issue is fixed there

Comment: Otherwise, you could try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694835/python-2-6-5-divide-timedelta-with-timedelta) question instead

Comment: when i am trying with python 3 i am getting py_vollib.black_scholes.implied_volatility module not found error

Comment: Did you try to install it with ```pip3```?

Comment: TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type datetime.timedelta which has no callable exp method
getting this error

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see (I am used to Python3.+) you are trying to get the difference between 2 dates (expiry and current) in days (I am guessing that it is why you are dividing their difference by one day). To get that difference as an integer you could use (MWE):

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

currentTime = datetime(2020, 11, 15, 15, 30)
expiryTime = datetime(2020, 11, 19, 15, 30)

tl = expiryTime - currentTime
print(tl)
a = tl.days
print(a, type(a))
```

Then you can use the accrual period in your function as a floating point: `float(tl.days) / 365`.